# Double.parse() in C# for data downloaded from webpage

Tags: c#, parsing, double

The following code, I download information from a website. In this example, I want to extract the information and store result in the double variable called myInfo. In this example, the information in a text: "10,000.00". I need to convert this into a double and store the information in the variable myInfo.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
using System.Xml;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Net;
using System.IO;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string url = "http://www.eurexchange.com/exchange-en/products/idx/stx/blc/19068!quotesSingleViewOption?callPut=Call&maturityDate=201412";

            var webGet = new HtmlWeb();
            var document = webGet.Load(url);

            var pricesAndQuotesDataTable = (from elem in document.DocumentNode.Descendants()
                    .Where(d =>
                    d.Attributes["class"] != null && d.Attributes["class"].Value == "toggleTitle" &&
                    d.ChildNodes.Any(h => h.InnerText != null && h.InnerText == "Prices/Quotes"))
                                            select elem.Descendants()
                                            .FirstOrDefault(
                                            d => d.Attributes["class"] != null && d.Attributes["class"].Value == "dataTable")).FirstOrDefault();

            if (pricesAndQuotesDataTable != null)
            {
                var dataRows = from elem in pricesAndQuotesDataTable.Descendants()
                               where elem.Name == "tr" && elem.ParentNode.Name == "tbody"
                               select elem;

                foreach (var row in dataRows)
                {
                    var dataColumns = (from col in row.ChildNodes.Where(n => n.Name == "td")
                                       select col).ToList();
                    double myInfo = double.Parse(dataColumns[0].InnerText, NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

With the code above, I get an error:

```
An unhandled exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Input string was not in a correct format.
```

So there is a format problem. But how can I fix it? I have also tried using:

```
double myInfo  = Double.Parse(dataColumns[0].InnerText, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

but without success. 
I would like it to be flexible enough to work with US format and European format as well. Thank you.

Comment: You should almost always use `Double.TryParse` instead of Parse() to avoid exceptions.

Comment: You need to parse in a culture that has `,` for the thousands separator. Your current culture and `InvariantCulture` do *not*.

Comment: What does that mean: "but without success"? It should be parsed without a problem with `Double.Parse("10,000.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or `double.Parse("10,000.00", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo)`.

Comment: Tim, I get the same error "Input string was not in a correct format". My example is ready to run so you can see that it actually doesn't parse correctly.

Comment: There is no "European format". For some examples of the possibilities in Europe, see [Decimal mark at Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_mark#Examples_of_use). If you are lucky, the web page will have the language specified in it: [The html element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/semantics.html#the-html-element).

Comment: @mickG: i've run it before i've posted the comment and it worked without a problem (of course only the second approach).

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment, it won't work for the page in your example because it says `lang="en"` but presents the numbers in German format. Sigh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
    var numberFormatInfo = new NumberFormatInfo();
    numberFormatInfo.NumberDecimalSeparator = ".";
    numberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator = ",";
    double result;
    if (double.TryParse("10,000.00", NumberStyles.Any, numberFormatInfo, out result))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you, looking at Tim Schmelter answer, it seems that the solution you propose is less flexible, since I have to change the separator in case I have a new website to get data from. Is there a way to make this more flexible? Can I just create two cases and switch between them using double.TryParse()?

Comment: I also had to change the CurrencyDecimalSeparator and CurrencyGroupSeparator to make it work in my example, but looks as a better solution overall. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to support multiple formats you could use a `double.TryParse` with different cultures:

```
string[] samples = { "10,000.00", "10.000,00" };
CultureInfo deDE = new CultureInfo("de-DE");  // to support your "European format"
NumberStyles style = NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands;

foreach (string sample in samples)
{
    double value;
    bool parsable = double.TryParse(sample, style, NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo, out value);
    if(!parsable)
        parsable = double.TryParse(sample, style, deDE, out value);
    Console.WriteLine(value); // output 10000 with both
}
```

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you! Can I ask you if this is generic enough to cover all the cases I might find downloading data from web? It seems so to me.

Comment: @mickG: what are "all cases"? There will be formats which aren't supported since you have said that you want to support `InvariantInfo` and "european format" only. You have to test it yourself if it works. If not you could edit this or ask another question ;)

Comment: I mean, I can have a website where "." is decimal separator and another where "," is decimal separator. But there shouldn't be other possible cases with characters other than "," or "." used as separator. So your solution looks flexible enough to cover all cases I might find in the future. Am I wrong?

Comment: @mickG: of course it's possible that you run into problems. Consider this: `"10,00"`, it will be parsed successfully in both, invariant and german, in the former it is `1000.0` and in the latter it is `10.0`. It's impossible to support every possible format. All the more if you don't know at all what format the site uses.

Comment: You're right, thanks for pointing this out. For this reason it seems that Jose M's proposal is more adequate in this case. I just need to make sure to change the separators according to what is used in the website. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @mickG: i don't know in what way it is more appropriate since he doesn't answer your question how to support formats with dots as group separator and commas as decimal separator as used by half the world. But never mind. That was already solved by your second approach: `Double.Parse("10,000.00", NumberFormatInfo.InvariantInfo);`

Comment: I was just considering your example. If I explicitly say that my decimal separator is "," then in your "10,00" case I won't get the wrong value since it will return 10,00. Am I missing something?

Comment: @mickG: but you wanted to "be flexible enough to work with US format and European format". So if you parse a value `10,00` that could be US- or "EU"-format. If you just want to support comma as decimal separator the question is pointless, isn't it? So if you don't know if the site uses `,` or `.` as separator the first will win. If that's `InvariantInfo` you get `1000` instead of `10`.